# クラス内に存在するロギング用の記述について

Tags: visual-studio, vb.net, delegate

.NET Framework4.0にて開発を行っております。
クラス内にロギング用の記述がいたるところに散らばってしまい、
また、クラス内にログ出力記述が入る事によって、クラスが汎用的に使用できなくなり、
可読性も下がってしまっているので、そこを解決したいと思い、質問させて頂きます。

現状は以下の通りです。

```
private class x
private sub exec()
--処理開始のログ出力記述
--処理1
　　----クラスX.メソッドA
　　----クラスX.メソッドAでXX件のデータを処理
  　----クラスX.メソッドAが正常終了しました
--処理2
　　----クラスY.メソッドA
　　----クラスY.メソッドAでXX件のデータを処理
  　----クラスY.メソッドAが正常終了しました
--処理終了のログ出力記述
End sub
end class
```

ロギング出力用のクラスを用意してあり、そのクラスのメソッドを、ログ出力のタイミングで
引数を渡して呼び出しているのですが、複数のクラスに記述がまたがってしまったりと、
とにかく煩雑になってしまいます。
また、問題解決の目的がロギングのみではなく、処理進行を表すフォームウィンドを操作する際にも同じ仕組が必要となってきています。

http://www.itmedia.co.jp/im/articles/0410/20/news086.html
このサイトを参考にAOPやDIに関して色々と調べてみたのですが、具体的な解決策にたどり着けませんでした。

何か具体的な解決策をご存知でしたら、お願いいたします。

Comment: 使用してる.NETのversionとかも書いた方が良いと思います。
logの出力は、オリジナルのclassでやってるんですよね？

Comment: 説明が足りず、申し訳ありません。log出力に関しては、オリジナルのクラスを使用しています。

Comment: `クラス内にログ出力記述が入る事によって、クラスが汎用的に使用できなくなり、`とご自分で書かれているように、log出力をmethod呼び出し元で行うように変えるの試みては？

Comment: あと、煩雑と一言で片付けられていますが、複数機能から呼び出されるmethod内にlog出力を書いただけでは煩雑にも可読性にも悪影響は無いと思うんですが？

Comment: 仰る通りですね。少し構造を変えてみようと思います。ただ、.NETのAOPについては、興味があるので、引き続き、皆様の解答を参考にさせて頂きたいと思います。

Answer (score 2):

.NETであれば、[PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/)はいかがでしょうか。
商用目的でも無料（[このページ](https://www.postsharp.net/purchase/faq)の「Can I use PostSharp Express for commercial products?」）で使えます。
無料版は機能制限がありますが、ログ出力であれば十分だと思います。

C#の例で申し訳ないですが、こんな感じで使います：

```cs
[MyLogging]
public class ClassX
{
    public int MethodA(...)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

`MyLogging`属性はPostSharpのライブラリにあるクラスを継承して自分で作ります。

```cs
public sealed class MyLoggingAttribute : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
     public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
     {
         // 対象のメソッドの処理の前に呼ばれる
         // args に引数とか対象クラスのインスタンスとか入ってる
     }
     public override void OnExit(MethodExecutionArgs args)
     {
         // 対象のメソッドの処理の後（returnの後）に呼ばれる
         // args はOnEntryのものと同じだが、戻り値も入ってる
     }
}
```

この属性をクラスに付けると、そのクラスのメソッドが呼ばれるたびに、`OnEntry`と`OnExit`が呼ばれるので、そこでログ出力処理とか書けばOKです。
クラスではなくメソッドに属性をつければ、そのメソッドだけログ出力できます。

ただ、「XX件のデータを処理」のような出力をするには何らかの工夫が必要だと思います。
必ず件数を戻り値で返すようにするとか・・・

PostSharpは、Visual Studioの「拡張機能と更新プログラム」で、「オンライン」から検索してインストールすればすぐ使えます。

補足ですが、AOPフレームワークには色々な実現方法があり、PostSharpは「ビルド時にILを書き換える」という方式を採っています。
なので、量次第ですが、ビルドは遅くなります。
しかし、「プロキシクラスを使う」方式に比べて、「あるクラスを継承しなければならない」とかの制限が無いですし、実行時のパフォーマンスも有利です。

Answer (score 0):

設計例の参考になるのと、もしくは独自実装からの置き換えも検討できると思い、[NLog](http://nlog-project.org/)を紹介します。

```cs
using NLog;

public class MyClass
{
  private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

  public void MyMethod1()
  {
    logger.Trace("Sample trace message");
    logger.Debug("Sample debug message");
    logger.Info("Sample informational message");
    logger.Warn("Sample warning message");
    logger.Error("Sample error message");
    logger.Fatal("Sample fatal error message");

    // alternatively you can call the Log() method 
    // and pass log level as the parameter.
    logger.Log(LogLevel.Info, "Sample informational message");
  }
}
```

クラスの静的メンバーに Logger を生成して各クラスで利用します。その他の例は[Wiki](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Tutorial)に良くまとまっているのでご一読ください。
コードに記述するログ出力処理は、ログのメッセージとレベル(`Fatal,Error,・・・`)だけで、その出力先(`Target`)やフォーマットは[NLog.Config](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Configuration-file)でコントロールします。デザインが明快で気に入っています。

Comment: ご丁寧に解答してくださり、ありがとうございます。
無償でこのようなものが存在していたのですね・・・
一度どのようなものか、サンプルプログラムを作るなどして検証させて頂きます。